# Use a loop to assign values to variables in different objects with an auto "fill the rest with default values"

Tags: java, loops, object

I apologize for the bad title and my probable misuse of terms and general unfamiliarity with Java straight away.

What I am trying to do is write a loop that can either create a series of variables with user-defined names or allow a user to enter in values and strings that can be withheld for later use.

How I hope to use this is with a number of objects that have three variables attached to them. So in the first iteration, Object 1 gets values for its variables, the second Object 2, the third Object 3, etc. The important thing is that I be able to stop the loop and fill the remaining objects' variables with default values. I can do this without loops, since the objects are all created with default values and nested if-thens can get the job done from there, but I imagine that using a loop I could greatly decrease the amount of code I would have to write.

In case it matters, each variable would be a string.

Thanks for letting me (probably) waste your time with this (probably) noobish question.

Comment: Can we see some code please?

Comment: First of all, please understand that variable names hardly matter. Get the idea of "variables with user-defined names" out of your head. What matters most is object ***references***. One way to reference an object is with a variable, but if you want to associate an object with a String, then consider using a `Map<String, MyObjectType>`.

Comment: I'm not really at that point, I need help figuring out if there is anything better than using simple and repetitive if statements for what I want to do. And I understand that names don't matter, I'm not sure why I put that there now that I think of it.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the bigger picture of what you are trying to accomplish with your objects?  It may be the case that your problem should be handled with a different design, but it is too difficult to tell with the information currently provided.

Comment: Jean-Bernard Pellerin, in his answer, has a good idea of what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're asking. You currently have:

```
Ask for value, put into Object1
if not done
  Ask for value, put into Object2
else 
  put default into Object2
if not done
  Ask for value, put into Object3
else 
  put default into Object3
...
```

You want:

```
for x
  if not done
    Ask for value, put into Objectx
  else
    put default into Objectx
```

Unfortunately that's not really possible. There is a way to do something similar, but you won't have real "named variables".

Using a `Map<String, SomeType>` (or whatever it is in java) you can do

```
Map<String, SomeType> dict = new ...
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
  if not done
    Ask for value, put into dict["object"+x.ToString()]
  else
    put default into dict["object"+x.ToString()]
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I am trying to do. I'll look up on this stuff.